# Composing roles in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

Is there a way to compose standard text roles in reStructuredText? For instance, to format a string as both literal and strong?

The following do not do what I had hoped:

```
**``text``**
``**text**``
:strong:`:literal:`text``
:literal:`:strong:`text``
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible. Content passed into the function which implements the role (argument `text`) is not further parsed.

See [Creating reStructuredText Interpreted Text Roles](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-roles.html).

That said, you could implement your *own rst* role which would parse the text further via `nested_parse()` if you like - but that's not what are you asking about here.

### Additional details

Comment from `docutils/docutils/parsers/rst/roles.py` suggests that the nested
parse feature you are asking about was/is planned/suggested, but hasn't been
implemented so far.

```
# Once nested inline markup is implemented, this and other methods should
# recursively call inliner.nested_parse().
```

Comment: See also http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible

Answer (score 2):

(The following is hereby released under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/).)

If you have the ability to extend the parser (e.g. if you are using Sphinx), you can add a custom **role** that parses its contents. (Note that this will work for simple things like bold/italic and substitutions, but will most likely fall on its face if you try to nest roles or such craziness.

I use this:

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst.states import Struct

def make_parsed_text_role(class_names=[], node_class=nodes.inline):
    def parsed_text_role(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner,
                         options={}, content=[]):
        # Prepare context for nested parsing
        memo = Struct(document=inliner.document,
                      reporter=inliner.reporter,
                      language=inliner.language)

        # Create parent node
        options['classes'] = class_names
        parent = node_class(rawtext, '', **options)

        # Parse role text for markup and add to parent
        processed, messages = inliner.parse(text, lineno, memo, parent)
        parent += processed

        # Return parent node, and any messages from nested parsing
        return [parent], messages

    return parsed_text_role
```

You can use this via a Sphinx `conf.py` like so:

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder (conf.py).

project = 'My Documentation'
# ...

# ...paste the above code here...

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('foo', make_parsed_text_role(class_names=['foo']))
```

In your documentation, this will let you write:

```
This is :foo:`some **bold** text`!
```

In HTML, this will produce a `<span class="foo">`, at least for the default `nodes.inline` node class. Use of the generator pattern is optional, but it's super-convenient if you want to make a whole bunch of these custom roles.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, this is "possible" in a way.

Inspired by [@Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68865718), I wrote a Sphinx extension for this, which can:

- Dynamic creating roles that composited by multiple roles
- Make interpreted text of role can be parsed (a.k.a. "nested parse")

---

First, download the extension from PyPI:

```bash
pip install sphinxnotes-comboroles
```

Then, add the extension name to the extensions configuration item in your conf.py:

```py
extensions = [
          # …
          'sphinxnotes.comboroles',
          # …
          ]
```

To create a “bold code” role, continue to add the following configuration, which tells the extension to composite roles `strong` and `literal` into a new role `strong_literal`:

```py
comboroles_roles = {
    'strong_literal': ['strong', 'literal'],
}
```

Finally, you can see the rendered result here:

[image]

You can check https://sphinx.silverrainz.me/comboroles/index.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

An rST/CSS workaround using the ["role" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles):

```
.. role:: strong-literal(literal)
   :class: strong

This is :strong-literal:`literally  strong`.
```

It requires custom CSS for correct rendering.
The following works in most browsers but does not validate
(`<style>` is only allowed in the document head)

```
.. raw:: html

  <style type="text/css"><!--
     .strong {font-weight: bold;}
     --></style>
```