# How can I include a hyperlink reference inside an inline literal in reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx with reStructuredText, and I’d like to include a hyperlink inside an inline literal. However, predictably, if I write

```
The result has type ``Foo_ -> Bar_``.

.. _Foo:

Information about ``Foo``.

.. _Bar:

Information about ``Bar``.
```

then `Foo_` and `Bar_` are not turned into hyperlinks. If I change my document to use a `parsed-literal` block, instead

```
The result has type:

.. parsed-literal::

    Foo_ -> Bar_
```

then I get the hyperlinks I want. However, I don’t want a separate block—I want the code to be inline. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34516306/247696

Comment: There is a new Sphinx extension that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741528/407651

Answer (score 4):

You can get pretty close with substitutions.

```
.. |Foo| replace:: ``Foo``
.. |Bar| replace:: ``Bar`` 

The result has type |Foo|_ ``->`` |Bar|_.

.. _Foo:

Information about ``Foo``.

.. _Bar:

Information about ``Bar``.
```

This was inspired by the workaround for nested inline markup described here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible.

See also [Format text in a link in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743845/407651).