# Inline Code Link in Sphinx + reStructuredText

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

In Markdown, one can create an inline code link like so

```markdown
[`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)
```

Which renders like [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update). How can get a similar behaviour in reStructuredText / Sphinx? I tried (1) using a converter but it never results in something similar (2) nesting external link `` `link <link>`_ `` and inline code block `` :code:`dict.update` ``, but that din't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do this is using the [`sphinx.ext.intersphinx`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) extension.

In your `conf.py` add

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',  # the last entry does not use a comma.
    # 'sphinx.ext.autodoc',  # just for example so there is more than 1 line.
]


intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None)}

# If you having an `objects.inv` for local builds
# intersphinx_mapping = {"python": ("https://docs.python.org/3", 'objects.inv'),}
```

Then in your `.rst` file or in the docstrings in the `.py` files write a simple cross-reference. Notice that `dict.update` is a method thus the right role ([`:py:meth:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-py-meth)) should be used when cross-referencing. The following example

```
A simple text to :meth:`dict.update`
```

Would give the below HTML output (the tooltip and link of the cross-reference also included in the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The [answer of @bad_coder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67485802/9761768) works perfect when referencing roles of codes from other documentation (like `:meth:`, `:class:`, etc.)

If anyone would like to create an inline code link to an arbitrary hyperlink, I solved my situation with the [sphinx comborole extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741528/9761768).

In particular using it [toghether with `extlinks` extension](https://sphinx.silverrainz.me/comboroles/examples.html#works-with-other-extensions).